# Printing PNG image in Zebra printer

Tags: javascript, python, html2canvas, zebra-printers

I have an HTML page which has some texts and Barcode, 
I used the HTML2Canvas javaScript library to crop the part that I want to print from this page.

Here is the function:

```js
    printBarcode() {
        var element = jQuery("#capture")[0];
        html2canvas(element).then(function (canvas) {
            console.log("ready");
            var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var tWindow = window.open("");
            $(tWindow.document.body).html("<img id='Image' src=" + myImage + " style='width:100%;'></img>").ready(function () {
                tWindow.focus();
                tWindow.print();
            });
        });
    }
```

Now I want to print this PNG image in Zebra printer
how can I do that? do I need to use ZPL? or adjusting the printer driver is enough?
I've tried to adjust the printer driver but the font was too small.

Thanks,

Comment: Normally you have to use ZPL to print with a Zebra printer.

Comment: if you have the code can you share it, please?

Comment: I don't, sorry. But there are plenty of ZPL libraries available online

Comment: There is some example code in this question: [Converting PNG to ZPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57819550/converting-from-type-image-png-to-zpl-in-nodejs/58490617#58490617).

Comment: I  tried your suggestion  but when I use: zpl = imageToZ64(Image). I keep getting this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: o(...) is not a function, do you know how to solve it, please?