# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: o(...) is not a function when using ImageToZPL from zpl-image package

Tags: javascript, html2canvas, zebra-printers, stimulusjs

I'm trying to convert Canvas from HRML2Canvas to a PNG image and then convert it to a ZPL image 
to send ZPL commands to Zebra printer but I've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57819550/converting-from-type-image-png-to-zpl-in-nodejs/58490617#58490617)

but I keep getting this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: o(...) is not a function

does anyone know how to solve this, please?

This is my JS code:

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas'
import imageToZ64 from 'zpl-image'

export default class extends Controller {

    connect() {

   $('#barcode-print-button').click((e) => {
            this.printBarcode()
        });
    }
   printBarcode() {
        html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
        var Image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        let res = imageToZ64(Image);
        let zpl = `^GFA,${res.length},${res.length},${res.rowlen},${res.z64}`;
                var printWindow = window.open();
                printWindow.document.open("")
                printWindow.document.write(zpl);
                printWindow.document.close();
                printWindow.focus();
                printWindow.print();
                printWindow.close();
          
        });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

You need to capture the named export using:

```
import { imageToZ64 } from 'zpl-image'
```

And you are converting the canvas to a string using `canvas.toDataURL()`.  Just pass the canvas directly to `imageToZPL()`:

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
    let res = imageToZ64(canvas);
    let zpl = `^GFA,${res.length},${res.length},${res.rowlen},${res.z64}`;
    ...
});
```

Comment: thanks, it worked ! but now I'm getting this error  : main.js:66 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: pako is not defined
    at t (main.js:66)
    at imageToZ64 (main.js:66)
    at main.js:28       it can't access pako.js file i don't know why !

Comment: The `zpl-image` module is older code that assumes CJS or generic browser usage.  For the browser, it expects a global variable `pako` to exist for the zlib deflate used with the Z64 encoding.  Can you add a `<script>` tag in your html template to include pako?

Comment: You are right I added the script's references to the HTML just to try and it works !! I can now access the functions from my controller it's  really weird,, Thanks Mark !